# "find it hard to trust" vs. "have a hard time trusting

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, sentence-structure

> 1. You're not afraid that your employees will find it hard to trust you?
> 2. You're not afraid that your employees will have a hard time trusting you?

I'm curious whether both sentences are perfectly natural and mean the same thing.

Comment: They are different.

Comment: They have identical meanings to me. @Leesiyoung, can you explain how they're different in meaning? I think "to find it hard to <do>" means the same as "to have a hard time <doing> it".

Comment: @gotube “have a hard time mean” already experienced, but 'find it hard"
 mean that  employee find it hard to trust.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing, but they are wordy. A native speaker would opt for something shorter, like, "Aren't you afraid that they won't trust you?"

Comment: @Leesiyoung Only the tense determines when it happens. The expressions are the same

Comment: @gotube Really? I though that it was different, But after read you  sentence I can know it is same. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Have a hard time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20a%20hard%20time) means to experience difficulty doing something. In the example, the employees will experience difficulty trusting you.

Finding something [hard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard) means the exact same thing, using the 10th meaning of hard (difficult). In the example, the employees will find that it is difficult to trust you.

So I'm both finding it hard to see and having a hard time seeing a difference between the two phrases :-)